# AVPlayer doesn't play anything

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avplayer, nsbundle

I am doing something incredibly simple, just play an audio.
but it doesn't play anything. not on the simulator or device.

audio file is in bundle and preview can play the audio, I have also tried different audios nothing plays.

What could be the problem?, do I have to add delegate methods for avplayer?(if so that doesn't make sense to me)

I have also tried without avplayer item and different nsurl methods too...

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"JohnsPizza" ofType:@"aiff"];
    //NSURL *assetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"JohnsPizza" withExtension:@"aiff"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc] init];
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    [player play];
}
```

[image]

I have also tried but no luck

```
//    SystemSoundID sound1;
//    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)url, &sound1);
//    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound1);
//    AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion(sound1);
//    AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(sound1);
```

Comment: Why don't you use AVAudioPlayer instead of AVPlayer?

Comment: File eventually will be remote. plus it is 3 lines of code it should just work...

Comment: Just to answer why because it's not retained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you gotta retain `AVPlayer` object as it may set to nil automatically

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *player;
```